# how to return a pointer to template class from a function?

Tags: c++, templates, pointers, linked-list

```
#ifndef __linkedListH__
#define __linkedListH__

template<class T>
class Node
{
 public:
 T data;
 Node *next;
};

template<class T>
class linkedList
{
public:
    Node<T> *head;
    linkedList();
    Node<T>* returnHead();
    Node<T>* Insert(Node *head,T data);
};

template<class T>
linkedList<T>::linkedList()
{
    head = NULL;
}

Node* linkedList<T>::returnHead()
{
   return head;      
}

Node* linledList<T>::Insert(Node *head,int data)
{
 Node *newNode = new Node();
 newNode->data = data;
 newNode->next = NULL;  

 if(!head)
 return newNode;

 Node *temp = head;
 while(temp->next)
 {temp=temp->next;}

 temp->next = newNode;
 return head; 
 }

 #endif
```

In this implementation of a linked list, Pls help me with the declaration of "returnHead" and "Insert" method. When I call these methods from main function, I'm getting the following errors with declaration of both methods:

1.ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'Node' with no type
2.expected ';' before '*' token

Comment: I think you should define the last line as `Node<T>* Insert(Node<T> *head,T data);` notice the `<T>` in function argument.

Comment: please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/30914633/edit) your question with a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).

Comment: What is the error you're getting? You probably need to specify `Node<T>` in the function argument, but posting the error message will help people to recommend a solution.

Comment: sorry for poor posting of the problem.. have corrected now

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a few `template <class T>` and `<T>` components:

```
template <class T>
Node<T>* linkedList<T>::returnHead()
{
   return head;      
}

template <class T>
Node<T>* linledList<T>::Insert(Node<T> *head,int data)
{
 Node<T> *newNode = new Node<T>();
 newNode->data = data;
 newNode->next = NULL;  

 if(!head)
 return newNode;

 Node<T> *temp = head;
 while(temp->next)
 {temp=temp->next;}

 temp->next = newNode;
 return head; 
}
```

This need to repeat the `template` declaration header before each member function is one of the reasons why member functions of class templates are often implemented inline in the class right where they're declared.

Also, I believe the parameter `data` should be of type `T`, and not `int`. It doesn't make much sense otherwise.

As an additional note, you might want to give your `Node` class template a constructor (taking `next` and `data`), so that you don't have to initialise it from outside.

Unrelated issue: names which contain two consecutive underscores (or ones which start with an underscore followed by an uppercase letter) are reserved for the compiler & standard library; using them for your own things is illegal. Rename the include guard suitably.